# Can't produce a certain format of date when I use a customized date instead of now

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to format a date to a customized one. When I use `datetime.datetime.now()`, I get the right format of date I'm after. However, my intention is to get the same format when I use `1980-01-22` instead of `now`.

```
import datetime

date_string = "1980-01-22"

item = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
print(item)
```

Output I get:

```
2021-05-04T09:52:04.010Z
```

How can I get the same format of date when I use a customized date, as in `1980-01-22` instead of `now`?

Comment: simplest thing is probably `date_string + "T00:00:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrFuppes suggestion in the comments is the shortest way to accomplish your date conversion and formatting use case.

Another way is to use the Python module [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).  This module has a lot of flexibility and I use it all the time.

Using *dateutil.parser.parse*:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

# ISO FORMAT 
ISO_FORMAT_MICROS = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"

# note the format of these strings
date_strings = ["1980-01-22", 
                "01-22-1980", 
                "January 22, 1980", 
                "1980 January 22"]

for date_string in date_strings:
    dt = parse(date_string).strftime(ISO_FORMAT_MICROS)
    
    # strip 3 milliseconds for the output and add the ZULU time zone designator
    iso_formatted_date = f'{dt[:-3]}Z'
    print(iso_formatted_date)
    # output
    1980-01-22T00:00:00.000Z
    1980-01-22T00:00:00.000Z
    1980-01-22T00:00:00.000Z
    1980-01-22T00:00:00.000Z
```

Using *dateutil.parser.isoparse*:

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse
from dateutil.tz import *

dt = isoparse("1980-01-22").isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")
iso_formatted_date = f'{dt}Z'
print(iso_formatted_date)
# output
1980-01-22T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your trying to achieve?

```py
date_string = "1980-01-22"
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d").isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")
```

**Output**

```
'1980-01-22T00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: OP wants `Z` for zulu time / UTC, so basically `datetime.fromisoformat(date_string).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")` - but honestly, why go through the parsing to datetime, if the input already is isoformat and you just want to append zero time and Z?